# Match file with given extension

Tags: regex, qt

I'm working with QT's regular expression and syntax highlighting. 
I have to highlight all occurrences of the files with `.so` extensions:

`file2d.so`, `test.so`, etc.

This one: `QRegExp("\\w\\.so")` in the string `file2d.so` highlights only `d.so` part.

How to match all the word until space to get full name of the file.

Comment: What characters could the file names have ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is only matching on one character. You'll need to use a `+` to match one or more.

`\w+\.so` will match the full filename of *.so files, provided there are no spaces in the filename.

Answer (score 2):

You are only matching one character and your regular expression does not support all file names. The QRegExp you want is `QRegExp("[\\w\\-.]+\\.so")`